# Is it a good practice to delegate/return Observables and transform data along the way?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable

If I have some abstraction above the async work, e.g.: some jobs, some facades, some parsers together using inheritance to avoid code repetition. Is it a good practice to return Observables along the way when transforming data?

e.g. Return Observable from http client to some facade that uses map (resp) to use job specific parser. The facade returns that Observable with mapped resp to some data service which is subscribed to it. In subscribe (in the data service) output is set as next to BehaviorSubject property and observable is returned to some component which is subscribed to it.

The data service is inspired by [this article](http://blog.angular-university.io/how-to-build-angular2-apps-using-rxjs-observable-data-services-pitfalls-to-avoid/)

**Edit:** What about unsubscribing from observables resp. Subjects, I think that in this case I should do it in ngOnDestroy as long as I'm managing whole process manually.

Te reason for such abstraction is that I want to be able to add different jobs in a quick way without code repetition.

Thanks for an advice!

Comment: Please add the code to your question that demonstrates what you try to explain.